# Auto stretched div (width+height)

Tags: html, css

This is what I tried:

```
<div style="position: relative; margin: 0 auto; max-width: 800px; max-height: 600px; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: scroll; background-image: url('/design/clan_flag.gif'); background-size: 100%;">
    <img src="/design/clan_flag.gif" width="100%" style="visibility: hidden;" />
    <div style="position: absolute;">
    a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JDbHw/

as you can see, the text cant start at the top, because of the "helper" image, how to aling top? In addition, if you have thick enough browser, it will shows a horizontal toolbar (guess because of the inner helper image too)

Comment: What are you trying to do? Your question wasn't very clear about your goal. If you want to have all those a's start at the top add `top:0px` to the div styling..

Comment: yes, this was.... noob question it was :)

Comment: glad to help, I have made a response for your question. Can you set it as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To position the div with text on top of the image you can

- add `top:0px` to the styling in conjunction with `position:absolute`
- or use `position:relative` on a parent div and for the two(text/picture div) and set the text div to have a higher `z-index`